# get timebased uuid's upto 100s of nanoseconds

Tags: java, scala, time, cassandra, timeuuid

I am using this `libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.oss" % "java-driver-core" % "4.3.0"` library for creating time based uuid's. Although it generates time based uuid's it gives me upto seconds but i am looking for values in 100s of nano seconds

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.uuid.Uuids
println(Uuids.timeBased().toString)
```

The output uuid is something like `f642f350-0230-11ea-a02f-597f2801796a` which corresponds to 
`Friday, November 8, 2019 at 2:06:30 PM Greenwich Mean Time`

Please help on how to get time in milliseconds seomething like this
`Friday, November 8, 2019 at 2:06:30:0000000Z PM Greenwich Mean Time`

I want timestamp to be converted in uuid format for testing(tests accept only uuid format). i would then convert uuid back to time to measure some time difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few steps here. The first is to convert the time-based UUID's timestamp (which is in 100s of nanoseconds from October 15, 1582) to one compatible with Java's date functionality (i.e. milliseconds from January 1, 1970). Notably, you asked for better than millisecond precision.

Next, we need to interpret that date into the correct time zone.

Finally, we need to format it into text in the desired format.

Here's the code:

```
// this is the difference between midnight October 15, 1582 UTC and midnight January 1, 1970 UTC as 100 nanosecond units
private static final long EPOCH_DIFFERENCE = 122192928000000000L;

private static final ZoneId GREENWICH_MEAN_TIME = ZoneId.of("GMT");

private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendText(DAY_OF_WEEK, FULL)
        .appendLiteral(", ")
        .appendText(MONTH_OF_YEAR, FULL)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH)
        .appendLiteral(", ")
        .appendValue(YEAR, 4)
        .appendLiteral(" at ")
        .appendValue(CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .appendLiteral('.')
        .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 7, 7, false)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .appendText(AMPM_OF_DAY)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .appendZoneText(FULL)
        .toFormatter(Locale.getDefault());

public static String formattedDateFromTimeBasedUuid(UUID uuid) {
    ZonedDateTime date = timeBasedUuidToDate(uuid);
    return FORMATTER.format(date);
}

public static ZonedDateTime timeBasedUuidToDate(UUID uuid) {
    if (uuid.version() != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided UUID was not time-based.");
    }
    // the UUID timestamp is in 100 nanosecond units.
    // convert that to nanoseconds
    long nanoseconds = (uuid.timestamp() - EPOCH_DIFFERENCE) * 100;
    long milliseconds = nanoseconds / 1000000000;
    long nanoAdjustment = nanoseconds % 1000000000;
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(milliseconds, nanoAdjustment);
    return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, GREENWICH_MEAN_TIME);
}
```

I'd drop those methods and constants in a utility class for convenient reuse.

A couple notes:

- Lots of statically imported constants here. They come from `java.time.format.TextStyle` and `java.time.temporal.ChronoField`.
- I used `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` instead of the more common `DateTimeFormatter.forPattern(String)`. I find it more readable and am willing to tolerate the resulting verbosity.
- I tweaked one thing about your desired format: you asked for the time to be `2:06:30:001`; this code yields `2:06:30.001` -- a decimal point between the seconds and milliseconds, rather than a colon. This is more correct, but if you prefer the colon, just change the corresponding `.appendLiteral('.')` to pass a colon instead.
- You'll often find example code that defines DateTimeFormatters, ZoneIds, etc inline. These classes are thread-safe and reusable, so for best results, you should define them as constants, as I have done here. You'll get better performance and reduced memory usage.
- Note that the DataStax driver's `Uuids` class uses the system clock's millisecond-precision value as input, so you're just going to see zeros in the last four positions, unless you implement your own nanosecond-based variant. You could do that using `System.nanoTime()`, but there are some complications -- [check out the note on the JavaDoc for more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()).

To determine the amount of time between two ZonedDateTimes, you just do this:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(date1, date2);
```

The `Duration` class has [several useful methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) you can use to interpret the result.

Comment: thank you :). for the method ```timeBasedUuidToDate``` what do i need to change if it has return milliseconds to 7 digits ?
currently it returns ```2019-11-08T16:03:15.762Z[GMT]``` I would need something like ```2019-11-08T16:03:15.7621112Z[GMT]```

Comment: Well, those aren't milliseconds. Six digits would be microseconds; seven digits would be 100s of nanoseconds, which is the maximum precision available from the UUID. We'd have to alter every step of the process. Go ahead and update your question; I'll put the updated code together and edit this answer.

Comment: updated the question. thank you so much for your time and patience.
One last thing i would want after i get the date is to compare it with another date get the time difference. i am doing it with simple dateformat in java but it's giving me precise values. could you please tell me if there is an easy way ? Again thank you so much

Comment: updated answer. Don't miss the last item I added on the list of notes!

Comment: Thanks @Jake. i had to jump to some other work and caught behind this one. i will come back and verify it but want to acknowledge your answer and accept it. Once again thanks :)